# Grab/download images from multiple pages using php preg_match_all & cURL

Tags: php, image, curl, preg-match-all

So I'm trying to grab some images from another site, the problem is each image is on a different page

IE: id/1, id/2, id/3 etc etc

so far I have the code below which can grab an image from the single URL given using:

```
$returned_content = get_data('http://somedomain.com/id/1/');
```

but need to make the line above become an array (I guess) so it will grab the image from page 1 then go on to grab the next image on page 2 then page 3 etc etc automatically

```
function get_data($url){
 $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('http://somedomain.com/id/1/');

if (preg_match_all("~http://somedomain.com/images/(.*?)\.jpg~i", $returned_content, $matches)) {

$src = 0;
      foreach ($matches[1] as $key) {

if(++$src > 1) break;

          $out = $key;
      }

      $file = 'http://somedomain.com/images/' . $out . '.jpg';


$dir = 'photos'; 

$imgurl = get_data($file);

file_put_contents($dir . '/' . $out . '.jpg', $imgurl);

echo  'done';
}
```

As always all help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to use PHP for that? Not that it's not possible, but depending on what you want to do in the end, you might run into many issues that are more often better solved half-automated.

Comment: PHP is currently the only code I know (ex html, css) the end result of this is to download a few images for myself to browse at a later date but theres about 100 images and I don't want to visit each page "right click >> save as".

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Why not run it in a loop for each of the pages? If your code works for one page, it should work for many. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have been trying to do that but always seem to get error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was pretty confusing, because it sounded like you were only interested in saving one image per page. But then the code makes it look like you're actually trying to save every image on each page. So it's entirely possible I completely misunderstood... But here goes.

Looping over each page isn't that difficult:

```
$i = 1;
$l = 101;

while ($i < $l) {
    $html = get_data('http://somedomain.com/id/'.$i.'/');
    getImages($html);
    $i += 1;
}
```

The following then assumes that you're trying to save *all* the images on that particular page:

```
function getImages($html) {
    $matches = array();
    $regex = '~http://somedomain.com/images/(.*?)\.jpg~i';
    preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $img) {
        saveImg($img);
    }
}

function saveImg($name) {
    $url = 'http://somedomain.com/images/'.$name.'.jpg';
    $data = get_data($url);
    file_put_contents('photos/'.$name.'.jpg', $data);
}
```

Comment: I actually got my foreach loop working I just had to move my coding around a little, but yours works and is alot cleaner to thanks!